# Remove all caches using contains keyword

Tags: c#, .net, caching, c#-4.0, memcached

This is how I am creating a cache key

```
string cachekey_base = "IR_";
string symbol = "AUD";
static string id = "12345";

string cacheKey_Quote = $"{cachekey_base}{symbol}{id}Quote";
```

The id is generated randomly so if I know the id then simply remove the cache like this

```
    MemoryCache.Default.Remove(key);
```

But the problem is `Id` can be any random number.

So is there e a way to remove using contains keyword.

For example in my case remove all cache if key contains `"IR_"

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated .

Thanks in advance`

Comment: Can you enumerate them and delete one by one?

Comment: yes i can but is there more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can filter keys you want to remove them then iterate over these keys and remove them
as following:

```
var removedKeys = MemoryCache.Default.Where( x=> x.Key.Contains("IR_")).Select(x=> x.Key).ToList();
foreach(var key in removedKeys)
    MemoryCache.Default.Remove(key);
```